# Pad variable length sequences in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to feed a CNN output into an RNN in TensorFlow.

The CNN processes 10 images and outputs a tensor of shape (1, 230, 2048). Where 230 is the total number of sequences for all images and 2048 is the length of each sequence.

I keep track of the number of sequences for each image in a vector. For example:

`[1, 9, 25, 29, 31, 10, 23, 29, 37, 36]`

I can get the max sequence number, in this case it will be 37.

The question is how to pad the (1, 230, 2048) tensor at different positions so that all the images are represented with the same number of sequences (37 in this example) ?

The final tensor should be of shape (1, 370, 2048).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a short code that solved it. Here's a small example with 6 images having different sequence numbers (I inserted spacing in the tensor for clarity).

```
vec = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 

        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 

        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],

        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],

        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],

        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]], dtype=tf.float32)

seqLens = [4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
maxLen = max(seqLens)

NFeatures = 8
BatchSize = 6

n = 0
offset = sum(seqLens[0:(n)])
indices = tf.reshape(tf.range(offset, seqLens[n]+offset), [seqLens[n], 1])
res = tf.gather_nd(vec, [indices])
res_as_vector = tf.reshape(res, [-1])
zero_padding = tf.zeros([NFeatures * maxLen] - tf.shape(res_as_vector), dtype=res.dtype)
a_padded = tf.concat(0, [res_as_vector, zero_padding])
result = tf.reshape(a_padded, [maxLen, NFeatures])
Inputs2 = result

for n in range(1, BatchSize):
    offset = sum(seqLens[0:(n)])
    indices = tf.reshape(tf.range(offset, seqLens[n]+offset), [seqLens[n], 1])
    res = tf.gather_nd(vec, [indices])
    res_as_vector = tf.reshape(res, [-1])
    zero_padding = tf.zeros([NFeatures * maxLen] - tf.shape(res_as_vector), dtype=res.dtype)
    a_padded = tf.concat(0, [res_as_vector, zero_padding])
    result = tf.reshape(a_padded, [maxLen, NFeatures])
    Inputs2 = tf.concat(0, [Inputs2, result])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(Inputs2))
```

The output should look like this:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.]
 [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

'

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`tf.pad`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard9/tf.pad.md). You pass it a list of pairs - one pair for each dimension.

Comment: The things is that I need to pad regions inside the tensor. Not the tensor as a whole.